# mlflow: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE Parameters can not be modified after a value is set

Tags: python, mlflow, mlops

I get the following exception raised, help me please

```
mlflow.exceptions.RestException: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Response:
{
  'Error': {
    'Code': 'ValidationError',
    'Severity': None,
    'Message': 'Parameters can not be modified after a value is set.',
    'MessageFormat': None,
    'MessageParameters': None,
    'ReferenceCode': None,
    'DetailsUri': None,
    'Target': None,
    'Details': [],
    'InnerError': None,
    'DebugInfo': None,
    'AdditionalInfo': None
  },
  'Correlation': {
    'operation': '13b09a7297c0e920a41eeaa728c4cb4e',
    'request': 'ae8a75a01a168e65'
  },
  'Environment': 'westeurope',
  'Location': 'westeurope',
  'Time': '2022-12-22T23:37:07.4626959+00:00',
  'ComponentName': 'mlflow',
  'error_code': 'INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE'
}
```

my code pretty much looks like this

```
mlflow.start_run()
mlflow.log_params({'key1':1, 'key2':2})
mlflow.log_param('key3', 3) //Exception raised
```

PS: the mlflow version  i am using is 2.1.0

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code, there's an extra curly bracket in `mlflow.log_param('key3', 3})`

Comment: sorry thats a typo in the question, even with the correct syntax i get the same error

Comment: Basically, it shouldn't give you an error. I think that maybe the `mlflow.start_run()` is using an old run. Did you tried logging all the params with `key3`?

Comment: This might be a bug. Check if you get the same error when you run mlflow 2.1.1.